# ng-model manipulating value when typing and displaying

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-model

I have the following variable:

```
$scope.pixelWidth = "30px";
```

And I have an input box like so:

```
<input ng-model="pixelWidth" />
```

I'd like for the input box to only have the numbers inside it but still insert the **px** into `$scope.pixelWidth` while typing.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to create a directive and add formatters and parsers to the [ngModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController). See [working version on plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vuLSh8bIWrOevvtZTsCG?p=preview)

Directive:

```
app.directive('modelSuffix', [function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    require: '^ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attributes, ngModelController) {
          var suffix = attributes.modelSuffix;
          // Pipeline of functions called to read value from DOM 
          ngModelController.$parsers.push(function(value) {
            return value + suffix;
          });

          // Pipeline of functions called to display on DOM
          ngModelController.$formatters.push(function(value) {
            return value.replace(suffix, '');
          });
        }
  }
}]);
```

And use it like so:

```
<input ng-model="pixelWidth" model-suffix="px"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" name="userName" ng-model="pixel.value" ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: true }" />


var _myPixel = '0';
$scope.pixel = {
    value: function(pixel) {`enter code here`
     // Note that pixelcan be undefined for two reasons:
     // 1. Because it is called as a getter and thus called with no arguments
     // 2. Because the property should actually be set to undefined. This happens e.g. if the
     //    input is invalid
     return arguments.length ? (_myPixel = pixel.split("px")[0]) : _myPixel + "px";
  }
};
```

I'm removing the "px" in the setter and adding the "px" in the getter.

I hope this work for you!

Comment: Could help explain what is going on? I don't get it :|

Comment: I modified my response, take a look again. Maybe it's more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by watch funciton.

```
$scope.$watch("pixelWidth",function(VariableValue){

// remove "px" from your variable and assign it again

$scope.pixelWidth=newValue;
});
```

Comment: This doesn't make too much sense. If I added it wouldn't it just show in the input field?

Comment: then you just have to manipulate value before submiting to server side. angular is two way binding.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any way that you can accomplish this without using a second variable in your controller. If you change `$scope.pixelWidth` to include the 'px', that's going to end up in your input box. That's the magic of two-way data binding, except that in this use case the result may be less than magical to you.

You'll probably need to do something like react to the ng-change event on the input box to change a second shadow variable.

```
<input ng-model='pixelWidth' ng-change='addPx(pixelWidth)'>
```

in controller JS

```
$scope.addPx = function(pw){
  $scope.withPx = pw + 'px';
}
```